# How To Format Currency In JPGraph Using printf Formatting

Tags: php, jpgraph

JPGraph states it uses standard printf formatting for labels.  However, I can't figure out how to get my labels to format properly for USD.  I need the output to begin with $ and have a comma separator.  The string I' trying is:

```
$%'01.2f
```

Here's my code for setting the value format:

```
$bplot->value->SetFormat("$%'01.2f");
```

What am I missing?

Comment: For printf, I use $%'.2Lf - which is slightly different than what you are using. What are you getting?

Comment: $%'.2Lf gave me $f while $%'01.2f gives me everything except the comma separator.

Answer (score 0):

Use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) on the value before using `SetFormat` to add the dollar sign to the value on the graph. If you are NOT using Windows then [money_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) may be used to do everything in one shot and `SeFormat` would not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it. In my case it was:

```
$bplot->value->SetFormatCallback(array(new controller,'formatMoney'));
```

Then in my controller class, I did this:

```
function formatMoney($amount) {
    return "$".number_format($amount,2);
}
```